# How to group by the empty cell col ,also in the final result of aggregation in Azure Data Flow

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have 3 cols in my csv file

[image]

In group by section i mentioned : col1

At Aggregate ,I mentioned sum(col2)

Output i got like in Azure dataflow Aggregation transformation :

[image]
But My requirement is to include the empty valued col1 cell as one group like:

[image]

How Can I achieve this in Data Flow, I can manually fill up the empty cell with some rand value,but I dont want to mess the Client data .

Comment: Can you edit your question to format your input data in a table format? also give your expected output in a table format if possible.

Comment: Could u please check now.

Comment: what is the datatype of your `col1`?

Comment: its String dtype , and col2 is Double.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the same with your input data and its working fine for me.

**Input data:**

```
col1,col2,col3
,12.24,2022-04-07
2,13.34,2022-04-08
2,14.45,2022-04-09
3,14.33,2022-05-03
3,14.55,2022-05-10
```

In the mapping, I have set to **string** and **double** for `col1` and `col2` respectively.

[image]

For the empty cell, it took it as `NULL` value and it gave me proper results after aggregation.

[image]

After transforming the data to sink csv file, it gave the `NULL` as empty cell.

[image]

I tried with multiple rows with empty cells and it's working fine for me. Also, I had tried by converting the `NUll`s to empty strings with this expression `iif(isNull(col1), '', toString(col1))`) in derived column and it is working fine for empty strings(inplace of `NULL`) as well.

I suggest you try trouble shooting steps like executing after publishing and close ADF and try again after some time. If it results the same, then it's better to raise a [Support request](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/support/create-ticket/) on this issue for deeper investigation.

Comment: Hey Sorry , what if col1 is NULL ,its not grouping NULLS?

Comment: I tried with multiple NULL values, It is grouping perfectly. This is the result when I tried with multiple NULL values https://i.imgur.com/m1h5sP3.png